# How to properly use async awaitAll in PHPReact?

Tags: php, asynchronous, reactphp

I make a educational lesson with Async library https://reactphp.org/async/. Want to figure out how to work in async mode properly.

So I made a 3 scripts. All 3 scripts connect to database 12 times.

First script finish work in 26 seconds
https://github.com/Carsak/php-react/blob/main/create-connections.php

Second script finish work in 26 seconds too
https://github.com/Carsak/php-react/blob/main/create-connections-async.php

I read documentation and found this

> The previous example uses await() inside a loop to highlight how this
> vastly simplifies consuming asynchronous operations. At the same time,
> this naive example does not leverage concurrent execution, as it will
> essentially "await" between each operation. In order to take advantage
> of concurrent execution within the given $function, you can "await"
> multiple promises by using a single await() together with
> Promise-based primitives like this:

So I rewrote script and made 3 variant
https://github.com/Carsak/php-react/blob/main/create-connections-async-correct.php
This script finish in 2 second and does not invoke connecting to DB. No iteration has been invoked

Could anybody suggest why this script did not work?

Answer (score 1):

FYI: I already gave an answer for this question on GitHub, for better visibility I'll also post my answer here:

First important thing to note is that the `async()` function only works in tandem with the [await() function](https://github.com/reactphp/async#await) and does not "magically" make any blocking function non-blocking:

```php
Loop::addTimer(0.5, React\Async\async(function () {
    echo 'a';
    sleep(1); // broken: using PHP's blocking sleep() for demonstration purposes
    echo 'c';
}));

Loop::addTimer(1.0, function () {
    echo 'b';
});

// prints "a" at t=0.5s
// prints "c" at t=1.5s: Correct timing, but wrong order
// prints "b" at t=1.5s: Triggered too late because it was blocked
```

This means, `file_get_contents()` or using PDO will still be blocking in your examples. You can avoid this by using functions and components that are designed for non-blocking I/O. For example, instead of using a blocking PDO you could use https://github.com/friends-of-reactphp/mysql.

You can read all about async and await in our [reactphp/async documentation](https://github.com/reactphp/async#usage). I also gave a quick explanation on `async()` and `await()` in https://github.com/orgs/reactphp/discussions/546#discussioncomment-7640814, maybe this also helps.